# How many 3-digit positive integers are there whose middle digit is equal to the sum of the first and last digits?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $3$-digit positive integers are there whose middle digit is equal to the sum of the first and last digits?

Comment: Does $011$ count?

Comment: 9 that begin with 1, 8 that begin with 2, 7 that begin with 3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For middle digit n=9 (odd number) you have (n-1)/2 = 4 pairs and 1 single.
198, 891
297, 792
396, 693
495, 594
990

For middle digit n=8 (even number) you have (n-2)/2 = 3 pairs and 2 singles.
187, 781
286, 682
385, 583
484
880

Try to generalize these 2 cases, and you'll get the answer.
Also, be careful with the smallest ones: middle digits: 3,2,1.
I mean, for them the above observations/formulas may not hold.
So check them one by one by hand.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is 45.
we should start with the middle digit of 9, then 8, then 7,.....the last will be 1.
If the middle digit is 9, we will have 9 numbers: 198,891,297,792,396,693,495,594, and 990. The number of middle digit is 8, we will have 8 numbers, and so on.
so the answer will be 9+8+7+6+5+3+2+1=45

Comment: This question has a well-accepted answer. You are not contributing anything new. Please refrain from answering such old questions. There are many new unanswered questions